# Custom notification for whatsapp group

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, ringtone

I'm in a whatsapp group which requires some sort of quick reaction. I'd like to set a special (custom or at least non-standard) notification tone or sound **specifically** for that group (and *only* it).

Some clarifications:

- I know how to disable and mute a group, that's a different case
- I know how to set a notification for whatsapp, but it wouldn't me differentiate among many groups I'm subscribed to
- I know how to set specific sounds/tones for specific contacts in whatsapp, but this is a group, not a person

If anyone is aware of a [hidden] setting or a hack, I'll be glad to hear. Thanks.

Comment: not sure if this is possible! The closest that you can go is SET a specific ringtone for a Group(if you have more that 1 then not possible to differentiate between them ) and different ring tone for other WhatsApp contact. Read more here: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23776567

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to do the following:

1. Open WhatsApp
2. Long press on the chat that you need to set the custom notification for
3. Press `Group info`
4. Press `Custom Notifications`
5. Tick the checkbox at the top right
6. Change the notification tone, vibration pattern, LED light colour as required.

For what it's worth, I am using WhatsApp version 2.12.367, on an Android 6.0 device, but I doubt that it is dependent on Android version.